# Why can I call Fortran subroutine through f2py without having right number of inputs?

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

I am trying to learn `f2py` and I have the following Fortran code

```
      subroutine fibonacci(a, n)
      implicit none
      integer :: i, n
      double precision :: a(n)
      do i = 1, n
          if (i .eq. 1) then
              a(i) = 0d0
          elseif (i .eq. 2) then
              a(i) = 1d0
          else 
              a(i) = a(i - 1) + a(i - 2)
          endif
      enddo
      end subroutine fibonacci
```

which is compiled with `f2py -c fibonacci.f -m fibonacci` and later called in Python

```py
import numpy
import fibonacci

a = numpy.zeros(13)
fibonacci.fibonacci(a)
print a
```

The subroutine `fibonacci` called in Python did not get enough number of arguments, but the code mysteriously worked. By the way, calling the subroutine `fibonacci` with `fibonacci.fibonacci(a, len(a))` also worked!

Could someone please explain this? Thanks!

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. You code is not Fortran 77 anyway, it is at least Fortran 90.

Comment: @VladimirF Thanks! What part of the code make it Fortran 90? I thought I wrote the code with the indentions in Fortran 77.

Comment: `implicit none`, `::`, `enddo`, `end subroutine`  The message should be, forget F77 in the 21st century.

Comment: @VladimirF I am trying to translate some old Fortran 77 code to Python, I have to learn it.

Comment: OK, learn, but do not write programs in pure F77. Almost all Fortran 77 is still legal Fortran 90 and later so learning more modern versions *does include* learning most of Fortran 77. It is just nonsense to write pure F77 in 2019, even your short program here is full of Fortran 90.

Comment: @VladimirF That makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`f2py` knows that `a` and `n` are function parameters, and from the declaration

```
double precision :: a(n)
```

it is able to infer that `n` is the length of `a`.  NumPy arrays have a length, so there is no need for the parameter `n` in the Python wrapper, and `f2py` makes it optional.

Note that the code generated by `f2py` checks that you don't give a value of `n` that is too big:

```
In [19]: a = np.zeros(10)

In [20]: fibonacci.fibonacci(a, 99)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-e9497469fd10> in <module>()
----> 1 fibonacci.fibonacci(a, 99)

error: (len(a)>=n) failed for 1st keyword n: fibonacci:n=99
```

You can give a smaller value:

```
In [21]: a = np.zeros(10)

In [22]: fibonacci.fibonacci(a, 6)

In [23]: a
Out[23]: array([0., 1., 1., 2., 3., 5., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

You might find it useful to generate and look at the interface file that `f2py` produces for this function.  The command

```
f2py -h fibonacci.pyf fibonacci.f
```

displays

```
Reading fortran codes...
    Reading file 'fibonacci.f' (format:fix,strict)
Post-processing...
    Block: fibonacci
Post-processing (stage 2)...
Saving signatures to file "./fibonacci.pyf"
```

and generates the file `fibonacci.pyf`, which contains

```
!    -*- f90 -*-
! Note: the context of this file is case sensitive.

subroutine fibonacci(a,n) ! in fibonacci.f
    double precision dimension(n) :: a
    integer, optional,check(len(a)>=n),depend(a) :: n=len(a)
end subroutine fibonacci

! This file was auto-generated with f2py (version:2).
! See http://cens.ioc.ee/projects/f2py2e/
```

You can see from the generated declaration

```
    integer, optional,check(len(a)>=n),depend(a) :: n=len(a)
```

that `f2py` has inferred that `n` should be an optional parameter whose value must not exceed the length of `a` and whose default value is `len(a)`.